# Two classes, callback and unit testing

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have one class with static methods : this class wraps calls to the Twitter API

In a second class, I have some business logic.

Due to the asynchronousness behaviour of some methods in the wrapper class, I have difficulties to design the communication. Here is what I've done :

APIManager.swift

```
public class APIManager {
    class func getPermission(callback : () -> Void) {

        let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
        let accountType = 
        ACAccountStore().accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

        let callbackRequestAccess = { (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            ...
            if(granted) {
                callback()
            }

        }

        accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(setAccountType, 
                     options: nil, completion: callbackRequestAccess)

    }
}
```

Welcome.swift

```
public class Welcome {

    public func checkPermission() {
        APIManager.getPermission(getTweet)
    } 
    public func getTweet() {
        ...
    }        
}
```

I am not sure that this design in right or not.
I don't want to have a strong link between those classes, that's why I am using a callback.

Is this a classic design ?
Moreover, I don't feel like this behaviour will be easy to test ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will greatly improve testability by not using class methods here. Create a `TwitterConnection` protocol. Create a `SystemTwitterConnection` that conforms to it and manages things through `ACAccountStore`. Create a `TestTwitterConnection` that returns pre-set responses that you can configure for testing. You could even create a `KeychainTwitterConnection` to manage Twitter logins by hand without using `ACAccountStore`, or some other implementation if Apple comes out with yet another way to store these accounts.

Pass the appropriate connection to `Welcome` when it is created.

If the `TwitterConnection` protocol gets large, you should strongly consider splitting it up into smaller protocols, such as `TwitterAuthenticator` and `TweetFetcher` that handle fewer things (even if a single type actually implements all of those protocols). This can make testing much easier by allowing your test types to implement just a few functions rather than dozens.

The use of closures is probably fine, but you should stick more closely to Cocoa naming conventions. What you're calling a `callback` is traditionally called `completion`. I'd also follow Cocoa's lead on how to name methods. Rather than `getPermission()`, it would be `requestAccessWithCompletionHandler()`. This would help the caller understand that it has very similar behavior to `requestAccessToAccountsWithType(options:completion:)`. Don't built a new vocabulary for the caller.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

It will help you to decouple event publisher (Observable) and consumer (Observer).
Also you can have a special Observable implementation
which doesn't connect to anywhere but notify the observers with static content.
So you directly call `notifyObservers` method, for testing the behavior of Observers.